# What would you call a premature egg served as food?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

This might not be a common thing elsewhere, but here in Africa, when we slaughter a hen that has been laying (or which was about to start laying), we normally keep any forming eggs inside of it, cook and serve these with the rest of the chicken.

Now, I'm looking for a way to describe such eggs, when they are served, typically, with the chicken broth. Checkout the bit I'm writing:

> And it wasn’t just the plate, I had been given two small bowls as well; one holding the chicken broth that had flattered my imagination, long before it was ever served; the other held two generous pieces of chicken, and ***one small, premature egg***.

Does the phrasing and choice of words sound right or could I have used a better word to describe that peculiar kind of egg?

Comment: People from western cultures unfamiliar with this culinary practice might think **premature** meant fertilized but not developed fully into a chick, rather than not yet laid.   So perhaps "unlaid egg". Compare https://books.google.com/books?id=cfP6jHmSLnMC&pg=PT278&dq="unlaid+egg"&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin_avm1I7LAhWBGj4KHe56AOsQ6AEIMjAE#v=

Comment: Urban Dictionary mentions the Filipino word  "balut".

Comment: @TimRomano that reference is further interesting, as not only does it describe the kind of egg I'm talking of, all the different variants, from the tiny ovaries, chain of yolks, string of eggs to the "unlaid egg". I will take the later, thanks!

Comment: You may want to ask this question on the "Seasoned Advice" Stack Exchange site for cooking questions as it seems to be about the name of a particular dish and a specific cuisine: http://cooking.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that they are referred to as ***[immature or unlaid eggs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_(food)):***

> - The most popular choice for egg consumption are chicken eggs. .... Some recipes call for immature or unlaid eggs...

Wikipedia

Comment: Tim suggested "unlaid eggs" first, but since you offered it as an answer, I shall accept it.